# In google assistant sdk how to change the default in-built intent into our own custom intent

Tags: voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk

How to change this default inbuilt intent "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE", into our own custom intent like "intent":"com.devices.xyzz"?
what changes to be done in order to get the custom intent for trait.
Below is the actions.json data

```
  "actions": [
  {
    "name": "com.webos.actions.contentIntextManager",
    "availability": {
      "deviceClasses": [
        {
          "assistantSdkDevice": {}
        }
      ]
    },

    "intent": {
      "name": "com.webos.intents.contentIntextManager", 
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "number",
          "type": "SchemaOrg_Number"
        },
        {
          "name": "speed",
          "type": "Speed"
        }
      ],

      "trigger": { 
        "queryPatterns": [
          "run ($Speed:speed)? $SchemaOrg_Number:number times",
          "run $SchemaOrg_Number:number times ($Speed:speed)?"
        ]
      }
    },

    "fulfillment": {
      "staticFulfillment": {
        "templatedResponse": {
          "items": [
            {            
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Google Chrome run $number 
    times $speed than Mozilla Firefox"
              }
            },
            {   
              "deviceExecution": {
                "command": "com.webos.commands.contentIntextManager",
                "params": {
                  "speed": "$speed",
                  "number": "$number"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

**Here is the response:OUTPUT**
    {
"provider": "googleassistant",
"response": {
    "deviceAction": {
        "requestId": "5c31721f-0000-2413-8295-f403043942f4",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
                "payload": {
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "execution": [
                                {
                                    "command": "com.webos.commands.Launch",
                                    "params": {
                                        "appName": "YOUTUBE",
                                        "launchParam": "",
                                        "appAction": ""
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "devices": [
                                {
                                    "id": "my_webos"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}
    {
    "provider": "googleassistant",
    "response": {
        "displayText": "Okay"
     }
    }

Comment: Where in your action package are you using EXECUTE?

Comment: @NickFelker yes I updated please check the response output..thank you for your support. I have updated pls do check once. want to know how to remove this default "action.devices.EXECUTE" into our own custom intent

Comment: Please check this reference https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/intents

Comment: Ignore that page. It's not relevant for this Assistant SDK.

Comment: @NickFelker in actions.json file i gave my own intent name but at the response it always give "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE". My goal is to get my own intent name in response but not this inbuilt default intent. How to get this?